# Big Database SQL Query to Quickly Gather Data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query to get the number of payments towards a case, along with the specific case data in a database containing over 1,000,000 persons. Because I'm dealing with such a big database, I want to gather all the data I need with as few queries as possible, but I'm still a beginner when it comes to writing SQL queries. My purpose is to build an input matrix for a K-means clustering algorithm. Here's what I'm working with.

**Note**: this data is not my real data, but rather a anatomical representation of the data I'm working with.

For table `PERSON`, the **primary key** is `ID`.

```
_______PERSON_______
|ID   |Name    |Age|
====================
|1000 |Roger   |23 |
|1001 |Mary    |51 |
|1002 |Mike    |29 |
|1003 |Scott   |31 |
```

For table `CASE`, `ID` and `Case_No` together are a **composite primary key**. `ID` in this table is a **foreign key** of `PERSON`.

```
__________CASE___________
|ID   |Case_No |Case_Amt|
=========================
|1000 |01      |230.22  |
|1000 |02      |30.31   |
|1000 |03      |13.96   |
|1001 |01      |112.12  |
|1002 |01      |30.24   |
|1003 |01      |520.12  |
|1003 |02      |45.37   |
```

For table `PAYMENT` the **primary key** is `Pay_ID`. `ID` and `Case_No` are **foreign keys** of the `CASE` table.

```
__________________PAYMENT____________________
|Pay_ID|ID  |Case_No|Pay_Amt|Int_Amt|Clt_Amt|
=============================================
|100   |1000|01     |30.00  |10.00  |24.00  |
|101   |1000|01     |40.00  |10.00  |30.00  |
|102   |1000|01     |130.22 |10.00  |84.13  |
|103   |1000|02     |30.31  |0.00   |20.92  |
|104   |1000|03     |10.56  |3.40   |8.37   |
|105   |1001|01     |100.00 |12.12  |67.27  |
|106   |1003|01     |200.00 |0.00   |120.00 |
|107   |1003|01     |200.00 |0.00   |120.00 |
|108   |1003|02     |45.37  |0.00   |27.22  |
```

I essentially want to get all the data I want and for the specific `ID` and `Case_No`. Each instance in my input matrix will contain attributes for a case.

This is how I want each row of my input matrix to look.

```
|ID_and_Case_No|Age|Case_Amt|Number_of_Payments|Paid_In_Full|
=============================================================
|1000_01       |23 |230.22  |3                 |Yes         |
|1000_02       |23 |30.31   |1                 |Yes         |
|1000_03       |23 |13.96   |1                 |Yes         |
|1001_01       |51 |112.12  |1                 |Yes         |
|1002_01       |29 |30.24   |0                 |No          |
|1003_01       |31 |520.12  |2                 |No          |
|1003_02       |31 |45.37   |1                 |Yes         |
```

I want to be able to create this matrix in the shortest amount of time possible. I would like to gather all of this data with as few queries as possible. Is it even possible to gather this data with one query alone? I know for the `Paid_in_Full` attribute, I'll need to add the `Pay_Amt` and `Int_Amt` fields together then check them against the `Case_Amt` field from the `CASE` table.

The way I'm doing it currently is by getting all the `ID` and `Case_No` fields from the `CASE` table with this query.

```
SELECT ID,Case_No FROM CASE;
```

Then I store them in a python list and query the `PAYMENT` table with this query.

```
SELECT COUNT(Pay_ID),Pay_Amt,Int_Amt FROM PAYMENT WHERE ID in (?,?,?,...,n) and Case_No in (?,?,?,...,n) GROUP BY Pay_Amt,Int_Amt
```

Then I loop through each payment from the `PAYMENT` table and add together the `Pay_Amt` and `Int_Amt` fields and check them against the `Case_Amt` field. However, `COUNT(Pay_ID)` field in this query does not give me the right number of payments per case. It just gives me 1 payment for each row instead of the correct amount. Also this way of doing it will take me about 2 hours to completely collect all the data and fill the input matrix.

Again I'm still a beginner when it comes to writing SQL queries, but I'm looking for a query to end all queries. One that will get me all the data I want and format it how I want in the shortest amount of time.